# Python Pandas Pivot Table Reorganizing

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in following shape

[image]

But want to organize it in following shape

[image]

Values in columns shouldn't be count of reason. It should be value itself.
Need help with code. Actually i don't know how to even start

Comment: It seems that you do not care of `Case` column, right? Do you want to reshape regardless of `Case` column?

Comment: No, it is also needed to confirm against which case reason 1 is given, It doesn't make sense in above example but in complete data set it does